# How to detect when a TextField loses the focus in SwiftUI for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
TextField("Name", text: $name)
```

I found this method

```
func focusable(_ isFocusable: Bool = true, onFocusChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }) -> some View
```

but it's only available for MacOS, How could I do something similar for iOS ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the initializer `init(_:text:onEditingChanged:onCommit:)` present in textfield. There you will be getting an action triggered when you begin editing and end editing. You can find out the minimal example below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var greeting: String = "Hello world!"
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Welcome", text: $greeting, onEditingChanged: { (editingChanged) in
            if editingChanged {
                print("TextField focused")
            } else {
                print("TextField focus removed")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if you don't have other TextFields and you use the .numberPad keyboard, onEditingChanged: with never get called. Neither will onCommit:

Comment: I tried the same with .numberPad now and it seems to be working fine. XCode version 11.2 beta and device in which I tested was iPhone XS Max running on iOS 13.2 Developer Beta 4.

Comment: onEditingChanged: is called when it gets focus, not when focus is released (because if there is no other TextField in the view, the no other UI elements will become the firstResponder). The same applies to onCommit:

Comment: SwiftUI `.alert` triggers `onEditingChanged` functions with `false` value.

Comment: i am commenting here about the above comment stating '
SwiftUI .alert triggers onEditingChanged functions with false value.' i am having a issue with that. any idea how to make it change to true when user tap on the textfield?

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 58):

### iOS 15+

In iOS 15 we can detect changes with [`@FocusState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate):

```
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
...

var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { isFocused in
                // ...
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.onFocus` has already been deprecated in favor of `@FocusState`

Comment: @harrisg Thanks, I updated the answer to use `@FocusState`.

Comment: This is such an overkill to keep a state variable for each textfield just to be able to react on losing focus. It's sad that Apple depracted onEditingChanged...

Comment: how to deal with multiple fields

Comment: I miss onEditingChanged too. In multiple field situation I don't know how to deal with it (I guess you have to capture the previous focusedField, and compare with the current focusedField?)

Comment: @G.Marc Not a big difference if you have multiple fields. Use an enum instead of Bool, and inside onChange check if the value equals the particular enum case you're interested in.

Comment: I've got multiple `@FocusState var focused: Bool` when I use `.onChange(of: focus)`, I get like 100+ rerenders. Commenting the onChange out removes the re-renders. Seems putting the binding into the .focused does not trigger the re'render and writing to the `focus` does not trigger a re-render, only accessing does.

Comment: @Fabian try an enum for focusstate instead of a bool, and then you can bind to fewer focusstate vars

Comment: please note that `onChange` won't get called if text field loses its focus naturally, i.e. by clicking on return button