# How Can I change text display in textfiled aftere editing finished in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield

example

if focus in textfield will display text (number normal)

if not focus textfield will display x in 3 fist digit

e.g.

- textfield focus user type 123456
- textfield not focus textfield will display xxx456
- textfield focus again will display 123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate a `FocusState` with the field and then respond to changes in focus. See the answer to [How to detect when a TextField loses the focus in SwiftUI for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893919/20386264) for more about `FocusState`.

Here is an example of how it could work:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var masterText = ""
    @State private var visibleText = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Secret number", text: $visibleText)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                    .onChange(of: isFocused) { isFocused in
                        if isFocused {
                            visibleText = masterText
                        } else {
                            masterText = visibleText
                            if !visibleText.isEmpty {
                                let endRange = min(visibleText.count, 3)
                                let endOfString = visibleText.dropFirst(endRange)
                                visibleText = "xxx" + endOfString
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            Section {
                TextField("Another field", text: .constant(""))
            }
        }
    }
}
```